# javafx GUI rendering fail after windows sleep (or hibernate)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a simple JavaFx FXML application which is compiled with java 1.8 jdk.

My application works well until I hibernate Windows(or sleep it), after start windows again, my app faces some GUI rendering problem and some parts of it get invisible!!

Here is what happens:

[image]

And this is what my app really is:

[image]

I Should mention that i have the same problem with every JavaFX app running on windows...

my system config is:

windows 8.1

JRE 1.8

CPU: intel Core i7(notebook) with integrated graphic

Nvidia GeForce GT 540M(Driver is Updated)

[[This link is .jar file]](http://wikisend.com/download/415038/Color%20Chooser.jar)

Comment: i cant reproduce that ... your application stays exactly the same after hibernation. Most likely your GPU drivers are faulty _OR_ your GPU has problems with alpha values after re-draw oprations. In general, JavaFX is not yet suited for mobile devies and laptops - maybe JDK9 will solve this problem and finally implement proper mobile and touch support. Using WDDM drivers (windows update) sometimes proves to be a solution - if that doesnt change anything try proprietary nvidia drivers

Comment: What happens if you force a paint by resizing it?

Comment: @jatkin Because the border is invisible I cannot resize it. I also tried resizing another javafx app(by maximizing and minimizing) but nothing changed ...

Comment: Can you add a `onMousePressed` event to the background to see if it is also mouse transparent?

Comment: @jatkin the mouse event dosent work on the hidden area !!

Comment: Could you make the `-` button resize the window with this code: `stage.width = stage.width() + 1`? this will force a repaint of the window. If you can you should update you driver like specializt said.

Comment: BTW I can't reproduce the problem either...

Comment: Did you find any workaround?

Comment: @Juan sadly no....